# RelativeLayout "layout_below" Using ID in another layout

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I currently have two `RelataiveLayout`s in my android prototype.

I created a title id in the first layout by calling:

```
android:id = "@+id/title"
```

From another layout, I wanted to place an `ImageView` below the title, so I called in another layout,

```
android:layout_below = "@id/title"
```

There is no error occurring but I am not seeing it working.

Please advise me!

Thanks in advance :)

**UPDATE:** September 21st 2014

Okay I think I found what is wrong on the layout structure.

I use 1 actionbar layout to contain fragment layouts. But what I think is that, the layout

is more like overlayed not actually nested within the actionbar layout. That seems like why

"android:layout_below" did not work eventhough I do not get compilation/build error.

So the structure is like this:

[image: How I want to place the image under the title]

So the title is positioned at the same place for all different tabs,

and I want to place images or text below that @id/title in the actionbar layout.

Please advise once again ! ;)

Comment: It depends on your full xml layout. So you need to show it.

Comment: I think it is about your width and height settings. be careful about them. Be sure relative is not wrong here :)

Comment: @Enes Okay, I will check the width and height.. That could be the problem. I used "parent_match" for width and "wrap_content" for height but let me double check on that part. THanks!!

Comment: It would definitely be easier and faster to find out if you post the relevant part of your code. Thanks

Comment: I have attached the concept image of the layout instead of the code as I found that it is more a conceptual issue.. Thanks :)